# Can't connect to Web-Service running on VMware Player

Tags: networking, virtual-machines, vmware-player

I have windows 7 installed and I am running VMware player with Ubuntu as the guest OS.
I installed Etherpad which runs on http://localhost:9000 in the VMware player. In the VMware player itself I can connect to the site with localhost:9000. If I look up the IP of the VMware player, I get some IP address. The problem is that I neither can connect from the windows system nor directly from the VMware with the IP address.

vmware: localhost:9000 -> works
vmware & windows: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9000 -> does not work

I can't find a solution how to connect.
It's in bridged mode.

Comment: Can you ping the IP address of the VM from Windows 7?

Comment: yes I can ping the IP address of the VM

Comment: I'm not familiar with Etherpad but is there an option in the configuration file to set what IP address it listens on?

Comment: In the config file there is this entry: topdomains = localhost,localhost,localhost.localdomain - I tried to connect with 127.0.0.1:9000 and this doesn't work either (on the VM)

Comment: What happens if you add 127.0.0.1 in the topdomains setting?

Comment: I added 127.0.0.1 and it worked. Now I added the IP of the VM and I could access it via windows. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem had nothing to do with the VM. I had to add the IP address of the VM to the topdomains entry in the etherpad config file.

Answer (score 0):

The localhost 127.0.0.1 address **really** means "localhost in the VM" in this case. You can not access this address from outside the VM.

The service you want to connect to must listen on "0.0.0.0", to be connectable from Host side. Then you can use the IP address of the VM.